# Is it possible to create window containing form panel within ajax request success?

Tags: extjs, extjs3

Ext JS - I have created a window within ajax request success function.
But I get this exception in javascript console:
`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'labelAlign' of undefined`
What is wrong here..

```
Ext.Ajax.request({
         success : function(form,action) {
          var win = new Ext.Window({
            title : 'Update',
            layout : 'fit',
            id : 'appWindow',
            width : 800,
            height : 400,
            modal : true,
            items : [ that.updatePanel ]
        });
        },
        failure : function(form,action) {
            alert("fail");
        }
});
```

Comment: can you show the code where labelAlign is used.

Comment: I do not have labelAlign anywhere in my code.. `updatePanel` is a formpanel

Comment: Did you check if `that.formPanel` really refers to the form panel? What if you reference the form panel by xtype and have ExtJs creating it on the fly?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like to me that you are experiencing an issue with scope when you are trying to access your updatePanel variable.

When the success handler code is hit, by default scope is set to the browser window object, and so any variables your have declared in your JS code can't be accessed.

Instead, you should configure scope in your AJAX request code like so:

```
var updatePanel = {formPanel declaration here};

Ext.Ajax.request({
             success : function(form,action) {
              var win = new Ext.Window({
                title : 'Update',
                layout : 'fit',
                id : 'appWindow',
                width : 800,
                height : 400,
                modal : true,
                //Note I have changed that to this here...
                items : [ this.updatePanel ]
            });
            },
            failure : function(form,action) {
                alert("fail");
            },
            //Setting this line below will now allow you to access any variables defined in this JS class
            scope:this
    });
```

Give this a go and let us know if this works for you.